# I want to upload a video to eBay using API , but eBay API is not working can anyone guide me?

Tags: javascript, rest, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I want to upload the video to Ebay store using API , here is docs .
https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/media/resources/video/methods/uploadVideo
but there is not input fields in docs where I can added the video to endpoint from my localhost.
How I can do this.
Can anyone help me to upload the video to ebay using API.

What that video_ID means Even I still begin to upload the video

[image]

Even I pass my Old video ID what does this meant? return 200k

[image]

I am try to upload the video to eBay using API,
I am excepted that there should be a way to upload the video using API, but I am missing something!